# How can I make my Rust program link to another glibc?

Tags: rust, linker, cross-compiling, glibc, rust-cargo

I have a `crosstool-ng` toolchain for `i686-linux-unknown-gnu`, this toolchain contains a different glibc than the one installed in my host.

The path to my `libc.so.6` is:

```
~/x-tools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib
```

How can I tell Cargo to link to the glibc located in this directory instead of the system one?

I have already tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it doesn't work.

What works is to set in my `.cargo/config` file this:

```
[target.i686-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "i686-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc"
```

But that links my program with the GCC toolchain instead of Clang. I want to use Clang and just link against a different glibc.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `rustflags` in `.cargo/config`?

Comment: You might want to cross-post the question on /r/rust (Reddit), there are several users there who do cross-compilation in which picking up another libc is mandatory so they probably have a good grasp on how best to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kennytm pointed out, I can use `.cargo/config` to tell where is the new `glibc` by using the `sysroot` parameter:

```
[target.i686-unknown-linux-gnu]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-args=--sysroot=/home/ebarreto/x-tools/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot"]
```

The `--sysroot` parameter will contain the path to my sysroot where lies the custom `glibc`.

I still think this is not the most practical way to do that, but I don't know a better way..